# "Failed - Server proble​m" when trying to save a PDF in preview in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, pdf

I a previewing a PDF using the built-in PDF viewer in Chrome:

[image: Image showing downloading of PDF failing with an error message stating "Failed - Server problem"]

When I try to save it on my disk, I get a "Failed - Server problem" error message. How is that possible? I thought the PDF had been entirely downloaded before it got opened in Google Chrome built-in PDF viewer.

(If it matters, the PDF was linked from [this page](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-981-287-988-2_14).)

Comment: Could you close chrome and try again?

Comment: @NetworkKingPin Thanks, going back to the previous page and clicking again on the link to the PDF solved it, but I wonder why I couldn't save on disk while it looked like Chrome has it saved somewhere on the disk or memory already.

Comment: It is an interesting issue wonder what made it a conflict.

Comment: @NetworkKingPin I haven't seen this issue for a while, maybe it's gone now.

Comment: Glad it's gone. Chrome has bugs here and there it  directed everything I tried to download to a /fakepath the other day but then fixed itself

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered this issue because Chrome requires that a url pointing to a pdf ends with the appropriate file extension.

`example.com/myFile` can display a pdf file, but the download will fail with the message "Failed - Server problem". In order to be able to display and download, you would need to have the url `example.com/myFile.pdf`.

Answer (score 1):

I often encounter this problem and have found the following workarounds:
1) Instead of downloading the PDF directly, choose Print and then "Save as PDF"
2) Use Firefox

Answer (score 1):

I also had this problem downloading a PDF in a Chrome PDF Viewer
The Viewer open a PDF from a filestream or byte array.
I solved it by adding the length to the Header

```
Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Length", buffer.LongLength.ToString());
```

Please note - Internet Explore worked just fine!
Hope this helps